# Windows 10 - No Minidump created after crash

Tags: windows-10, crash, minidumps

I am struggling pc crashed that show up as a Kernel Power Error ID:41.
I if want to take a look to see if there is a Minidump with detailed info I see that there is no Minidump created.
I already follwed the following steps:

*Right-click on "My computer"
Select "Properties"
Activate the "Advanced" tab
Click on the "Settings" button immediately below the "Startup and Recovery" heading
Disable the "Automatically restart" checkbox below the "System failure" heading*

Even that did not work for me. Does somone else have another solution for me to enable Minidump?

```
    - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>6</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-19T14:36:26.463649200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1012</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-1EHM37S</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">true</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Thanks

Comment: windows needs a pagefile to generate a dumps. have you disabled the pagefile?

Comment: I used software crashdump. I used the build-in function 'test crash' and that gave me a crashdump. But under the circumstance my pc normally crashes it does not write a dump file.

Comment: Some more information. It only happens with more intensive tasks. And more specific. With CS GO, cant even get in match. And with Cities Skylines, in first seconds in-game. BF One & BF 4 are working fine.

Comment: post the XML output of the eventlog entry that you see.

Comment: JSFiddle to code: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vgMKEAoFrl

Comment: the link doesn't work. add the data as code formatting to your post

Comment: you haven't got a bugcheck, so there is no minidump. check all steps from scenario 3 of this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-clean

Comment: have you tried all steps from scenario 3?

Comment: Only not the PSU check, it is a bit difficult for me to get a spare one.

Comment: everything else is fine?

Comment: Can not think about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens before minidump gets a chance to write anything. I eventually chased an identical problem to Asmedia USB3 drivers that rejected a VR headset. You need to go through the process of what recent hardware has been added and what drivers have been added. You may be able to use System Restore via the install media.

The system would also crash without minidump trying to access safe mode.

Comment: I added a Samsung SSD a few months ago. But it also happend before that.

Comment: You need to strip the computer down to bear minimum - different ram if possible, different sata port for hdd, different power supply if possible and start from there. If it boots then it's a process of elimination.

Comment: Already did a RAM check: that was ok. Long project to figure the problem out, but I am going for it.